# Получить список всех видео из YouTube

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Пытался делать это простым `file_get_contents();` список видео получаю, но получаю всего 30, остальные не получаю так как они подгружаются ajax-ом.
Принял решение делать через API, но тут ещё хуже, грузит либо одно видео либо вообще возвращает 0.

```
$chanel = "UChpiJbaOTb8x9zhjGApQ3OQ";
$key = "AIzaSyBEiwHcpz6yA4iEF_V3W_t0Ax2-QlI79ck";
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&maxResults=50&id=".$chanel."&key=".$key);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Или возможно есть другой способ получить весь список видео канала?

Kye рабочий пока, потом изменю или отключу.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с сервисами Google, наверное, лучше использовать официальные библиотеки, на пример google/apiclient.

[YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#retrieve_my_uploads)

Answer (score 1):

Внемли совету - используй гугловскую библиотеку. Уж лучше так. Потому что самому разобраться во всех "прелестях" этого ужасающего полудокументированного чудовища - да проще повеситься.

Зря Вы вот так свой ключ выложили - по нему уже лимит превышен.

Суть в том, что Вам нужно было использовать не `videos`, а `search`, т.к. videos действительно по одному видео информацию выдает только (зато полную), в то время как search выдает до 50 роликов (но description неполный и не все данные можно так получить). И да, возможно где-то в официальной документации есть примеры с videos и там несколько результатов. Но не сейчас: апи менялось, а документация - неочень (где-то обновили, где-то забыли, а где-то гибрид остался).

В своём примере замените строчку:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&maxResults=50&id=".$chanel."&key=".$key);
```

на строчку:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&id=".$chanel."&key=".$key);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Ключ я уже удалил, мне же нужно было опубликовать что бы тот кто отвечает, нормально тестировал.